# Want to Auto-Save EVERY webpage I visit (as HTML or MAFF/MHTML) - Solutions?

Tags: browser, logging, history, web, url

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time, there are multiple possibilities.  This gets convoluted...

Basically the activity I want to automate is, on EVERY page any browser visits - the 'right click, save as, xxx.html) action so I have a completely saved record of my browsing history.

1. Shelve Add-on for Firefox does exactly this automatically in the background, and it works pretty well (it can actually use the MAFF archive html-as-a-single-file which is great, but this format slows everything down, so I just use it for HTML).

PROBLEM: I use 5 other browsers, so this isn't good enough to create a complete record.

2. I have looked into Cyotek WebCopy and WinHTTrack; both are essentially web crawlers which get fed a URL and then start stripping/saving it to HTML.  WinHTTTrack actually works ok, but it takes a long time (much longer than just right-click,save as, xxx.html in the browser), and worst of all it's NOT automated.

In theory what I would have to do is get my browsing history from every browser, export it as a txt file with addons (since browser histories proper are usually .sqlite files) and feed it to the program as a txt file, which it accepts, it would then go crawl that list of URLs to level 0 or 1 or whatever (you can specify the depth of the crawl in that particular program).

This is very cumbersome since it means that I can't automate the process really.  I need to manually feed URLs to the program.

3. As an addendum to this, I investigated URL logging at the router level/setting up a web proxy so I could generate a browser agnostic URL list of all visited pages.  In theory I could then feed that to the crawler, and perhaps automate it?  I haven't figured out to generate this URL log yet though - there are a few programs that seem promising: Charles (a web proxy with logging), and Fiddler (a web debug/logging tool) amongst others.
4. A program called Proxy-offline-browser looked promising as it does EXACTLY what I want by using a web proxy to grab every URL and then saving the URL automatically, but it's apparently quite buggy, old, and slowed the browser way too much.  I will try to contact the Devs to see if I'm using it incorrectly.

It also seems to only run on ONE browser at a time.

5. I don't think what I want should be that difficult.
6. In the abstract perfect what I want is this:

Every time ANY browser visits a website, the URL is logged (I think web history is sufficient, but sometimes web histories don't seem to capture every URL).  Those logs from every browser are then combined into a giant list of URLs.

Then, every URL is visited by the browser automatically, saved as HTML (or a better format).  And I would have it run every hour, or whenever the computer is idle, etc., on some interval.

7. Alternatively, I have looked into macros, since in theory if I just did the right-click save on EVERY page I visited, I would reproduce EXACTLY what I want.  Macros for browsers though don't seem to work since you need to actually RUN the macro manually which defeats the purpose to me.
8. Does anyone know how I could do this?!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you use 5 web browsers.  [Browsing History View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html) does a total of 4 browsers and seems to grab pretty close to every site visited but I doubt you are using Safari and IE is becoming less likely as well.  It pulls from the browsers themselves so it would be a 'post browsing' save.

It may make it easier if that grabs a couple browsers and you can find something else for the others.

**Edit:** Technically Browsing History View actually pulls 9 histories now(8 because it has pre-IE10 and IE10/11+Edge as 2 separate options)

Answer (score -1):

I am in the same boat as you. The only hint of a solution I have found is a [js tweak which POSTs to a local webserver when you visit a webpage](http://craiget.com/blog/2011/10/). If you find anything more or have found a better solution, I would appreciate the info :) I'll keep looking also.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.